# Fatal error: ini_set(): To prevent data corruption, you are not allowed to turn on the mongo.native_long setting on 32-bit platforms in Unknown

Tags: php, mongodb

Fatal error: ini_set(): To prevent data corruption, you are not allowed to turn on the mongo.native_long setting on 32-bit platforms in Unknown on line 0

http://localhost/rockmongo/web/rockmongo/index.php

I have installed 32 bit php_mongo.dll and open extension in php.ini and set the environment variables for php.exe and placed the libsasl.dll in system32 folder. 
I am currently using window 7 and appear this error.Can somebody pls solve the problem.Thanks!

Comment: Seeing URL to `localhost` means nothing for me.

Answer (score 1):

I turned off the ini_set("mongo.native_long",1); as it said not working on 32 bit. and run perfectly instead of preg_replace(): is deprecated and need a little configuration ! :)